# Detect if contour is simple curve without complex pattern or detect starting and ending points of contour

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

I have a problem with detecting if contour is a simple curve or line. I need to filter as many object as I can and leave only interesting objects for me. But it's not a goal to filter all unwanted objects. I have more logic to detecting required objects later but it cost a lot of time. So I'm looking for some low cost solution for filtering unwanted object before main algorithm take the part.

I have two examples from my application.

[image]
[image]

So I want to remove the yellow marked objects. And leave the green marked object. I don't circle everything, because they are so many :]. My idea was that if I can detect if the line is starting and ending in the corners of bounding box, but I dont'k know how can I detect where the line starts and ends. Or If I'm able to detect starting and ending points of contour I can decide it by their distance.

I use canny edge detection and find contours. And I have some basic filtering of object depending on their size.

I'm out of ideas and stuck at this part. I will be glad for your help or ideas.

Comment: you can assume a line, then test the pixels location how far they are away from the line. If too many pixel too far away or sth like that you dont remove the object. Or instead of assuming a line you could fit a curve and test average distance from that curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that HoughLinesP do the job.